# PERL поиск информации по всему документу

Tags: perl, скрипт

Есть некий файл test.txt, в котором 1000+ строк
Как на языке PERL написать скрипт, чтобы когда читался файл, и находил одну или более строчек с надписью difference found, то выдавал error, а в противном случае, если таких строчек нет, то меседж ОК ?

Comment: Можно считать, что это почти дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1404616/2739

Comment: согласен с KoVadim

Comment: подскажу, что строки на равенство проверяются через eq, а на вхождение можно через регулярку `if ($line =~ /difference found/) { say "<тут был набор символов>";}`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(first);

open my $FILE, "<", "test.txt" or die $!;
my $error = first { /difference found/ } <$FILE>;
close $FILE;

print $error ? "error" : "ok";
```

По сути, всё самое интересное происходит в строке `my $error = first { /difference found/ } <$FILE>;`. В этой стркое происходит чтение файла построчно и проверка каждой строки на вхождение. Для короткого цикла используйте функцию `first` из модуля `List::Util`. Описание этой функции можно прочесть в документации: https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#first